# How can you find the rolling correlation on tables filtered data?

Tags: excel, filter, correlation

I need to find the rolling correlation of columns A and B in the below photo. I figured I would start off and use a sample size of 80 to see the results. However, I face the problem that the correlation formula does not consider only visible rows. (Note: The table has roughly 4500 rows)

[image]

I thought I would be able to use the below formula to keep the sample size as 80, however, it does not work on filtered data.

```
=CORREL((OFFSET(A1,0,0,1):OFFSET(A1,0,0,80)), (OFFSET(B1,0,0,1):OFFSET(B1,0,0,80)))`
```

What options do I have in finding the intended results?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This should get you started: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/rolling-90-day-average-on-filtered-table.1126033/ , but in general it will probably require a complicated array formula or a UDF (user defined function, using VBA) to get this working.